# Comparing float and double for exact values with objects only

Tags: java, floating-point, equals

Im running into a problem where i need to have some sort of exact value comparison of two objects. The problem here is i have no idea in which sequence ill receive them... and both are passed as pure java objects, no primitives.

```java
public void compare(Object floatOrDouble, Object floatOrDouble){
  // How do we compare ? 
}
```

How would we compare a float object and a double object for exact values without knowing which one is which ? Is there already some sort of util for such cases ? Do we need to check their classes manually ?

Comment: Why not cast both to double? I mean it has a bigger foot print and is more exact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert 2 objects to Double then you can compare. but you can't cast an object to a Double if the object is not a Double.

So you can convert 2 objects to String then to Double using `new Double(object.toString());` then you can compare safely